# Replace matching brackets for parenthesis vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to quickly replace matching brackets for matching parenthesis (or any other opening/closing characters) in vscode?

Something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> but for matching brackets, parenthesis and such.

I'm currently replacing traditional JavaScript function definitions (redux action creators) for arrow functions, also I'm using airbnb rules in eslint in which the rule arrow-body-style needs to move the returning value immediately after the `=>` and because most action creators return an object literal it needs to be surrounded by parenthesis, that's why I need a mechanism to make the replacements easy.

I'm trying to change.

```js
export function hideServerErrors() {
 return {
  type: HIDE_SERVER_ERRORS,
 };
}
```

to

```js
export const hideServerErrors = () => ({
 type: HIDE_SERVER_ERRORS,
});
```

Comment: Have you found the answer? I am very interested in it too :-)

Comment: I haven't, very neat feature to implement right?

Comment: Perhaps you should make a feature request.

Comment: @seron I'll give it a try, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: This extension seems to handle that and a little more: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pustelto.bracketeer

Comment: Thank you, this is such an awesome extension, totally solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Remove brackets

Since vscode v1.77 (april 2023) there is build in action that can help in this case.

```
Remove Brackets
editor.action.removeBrackets
```

It deletes both matching parentheses by one hotkey.

By default bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

#### Changing brackets with this command

1. Put cursor to bracket you want to change
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to select content inside brackets
3. Press new bracket (that will automatically surround selected content)
4. Put cursor to old bracket again
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete old brackets.

Comment: It only took almost 5 years for them to implement since my question, thanks a lot for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, try this:

First, bind this command to some keychord, like

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+]",
    "command": "editor.action.selectToBracket"
}
```

Then, with the cursor just inside your first bracket (end of your first line of code), trigger the command, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> in my example keybinding.  The type your <kbd>(</kbd>  and you get:

```
export function hideServerErrors() ({
  return {
   type: HIDE_SERVER_ERRORS,
  };
 })
```

which I think is all you are trying to accomplish with this one step.  Given that you have a few things to change a **snippet** might be the way to go to make all the changes at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Quick and Simple Text Selection extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select), as referenced in this tip on [Smart Select](https://ihatetomatoes.net/vscode-tips-select-everything-between-brackets-quotes/) may be able to help.

With the extension installed, if you want to *replace* `{` with `(`:

1. Click somewhere inside the outer `{`s
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> to select the entire inside contents
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to cut the contents
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> to grab the braces
5. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the braces
6. <kbd>(</kbd> to add open/close parens (assuming you have the default option enabled to add the closing parens)
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste the innards.

When I tried this, it worked but formatting was whacky, so perhaps not exactly what we're looking for...

In your case, it looks like you want to *wrap* the `{ type: HIDE_SERVER_ERRORS, }` with parens, which is even easier - click inside, Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> to grab the parens included, and then <kbd>(</kbd> to wrap that in parens... or mix & match as necessary...

(I think Smart Select can do the same thing on its own, but it takes more machinations/steps/combinations...)

Not 100% convenient, but in some more complicated scenarios, this should be much better than trying to select/match the braces yourself.

Comment: how it's called the ctrl + k, shift + } command? The closest default command with that keybinding is **Fold Recursively** with `Ctrl+k`, `Ctrl+Shift+{`

Comment: "*With the extension installed*"... without the extension, you'd have to use some version of the Smart Select (`Shift+Alt+Right Arrow`)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Regex:
Find: `funcName\('([\s\S\r]*?)'\)`
Replace: `funcName['$1']`
it will replace things like `funcName('test')` to `funcname['test']`

Comment: I tested that quickly, that only would work for inline brackets doesn't it?

Comment: What do you mean 'inline'? Do you mean in one line? I think u can change the regex to support brackets in separate lines. But I don't know how. @Rodrirokr